# Why doesn't this JavaScript evaluation work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I only want to execure a ceratin code IF three input fields do not have empty values. So why doesn't this code work:

```
if($("#field1").val() != "" && $("#field2").val() != "" && $("#field3").val() != "")
```

Comment: Well, why doesn't it? Is there an error? If so, what error? If not, are the results of `$(...).val()` what you expect? If not, why not?

Comment: this should be tagged as jQuery.

Comment: Maybe it is an error somewhere else? (learn how to use JS console) 
Maybe your form fields have whitespaces? You should show us the whole script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do all three inputs have ids matching your selectors?  You may also want to check that the type of the values is not undefined like so:

```
if(typeof($('#field1').val())!='undefined' ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the input fields are named properly? They should have the `id` attribute for them set.

Comment: I am using jQuery so that is not a problem.

Comment: @Vachaio1: umm, whaa? The inputs must be named properly with the expected `id` attribute for jQuery to select them. That's how the system works.

Comment: My mistake. Yes, all the IDs are properly set.